# How to turn 3G on and off in Android

Tags: android, android-internet

I am an android developer, I want to run `3G connection` on or off via a button in my application.

Comment: That thread doesn't provide an up-to-date answer. Solutions given there stopped working after 2.2 and/or require root access.

Comment: Added a description of a possible workaround as an answer below. It works fine in one of my apps.

Answer (score 1):

I've done an extensive search on this topic recently and must tell there is no simple solution to this problem on modern Android versions, unless you run your app as root.

I found a simple, yet a bit limited, workaround though: 3G connectivity is active only if WiFi is down, so each time you are about to initialize a network connection, you must check if WiFi is up and connected. Below is some code for your sample activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    boolean enable3g = false;

    public void onCreate() {
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
        Button enable3gButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3g);
        enable3gButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyActivity.this.enable3g = !MyActivity.this.enable3g;
            }
        });

        if (enable3g || isWifiConnected()) {
            // do your stuff that requires network access here
        }



    }
    public boolean isWifiConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnected();
    }
}
```

In AndroidManifest you need `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission (and a declaration of your activity of course):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application .....>
    <activity android:name="MyActivity" />
```

If WiFi is not connected (the `isWifiConnected()` method returns `false`), do not start to connect. An existing TCP connection cannot "jump" from one network to another so it will just time out if WiFi connectivity is broken, making the solution quite safe.

The limitation is, that you must be able to control your application's connections. If you are using WebView, or some 3rd-party piece of software, it may get tricky.

Comment: my objectif is to create a button, and user can turn on the internet from it ! i didn't find a solution

Comment: I have expanded the example to include a sample activity. It assumes you have defined a button in a layout file `my_layout.xml` and the id of the button is `button3g`. You need to wrap all the code that requires network in simple `if` blocks, that check that either `enable3g` is set to `true`, which is done by means of your button, or that WiFi is available.

Comment: should i add some thing in the manifest ?

Comment: Yes, you need the `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission (sorry I forgot to add it earlier) and of course the declaration of your activity. Edited the answer.

Comment: Could you please upvote the answer if you find it useful?

Comment: i am sorry but it doesn t work :(

Comment: Can you describe the problem? As I wrote, it's a workaround. You shouldn't expect the 3G to get disabled. It should just prevent your app from using it.